# Health insurance coverage for recent immigrant

Tags: insurance, washington, immigration

How does someone obtain health insurance coverage in Washington state as an immigrant.

Comment: Does your employer offer health insurance?

Comment: Looks like this is the site for Washington's healthcare exchange, might be the best place to start if your employer doesn't offer health insurance: https://www.wahbexchange.org/new-customers/application-quick-tips/steps-to-apply/

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers for immigrant healthcare rules and regulations can be found at https://www.healthcare.gov/immigrants/

Here are some of the important things to know:

> Most people in the following groups are eligible for coverage through
>   the Health Insurance Marketplace:
>
> U.S. citizens, U.S. nationals, and **Lawfully present immigrants**

In the Affordable Care Act provisions a lawfully present immigrant means:

he term “lawfully present” includes immigrants who have:

- “Qualified non-citizen” immigration status without a waiting period
  (see details below)
- Humanitarian statuses or circumstances (including
  Temporary Protected Status, Special Juvenile Status, asylum
  applicants, Convention Against Torture, victims of trafficking)
- Valid non-immigrant visas
- Legal status conferred by other laws (temporary resident status, LIFE Act, Family Unity individuals) See a full list of immigration statuses eligible for Marketplace coverage.

There is also potential for lawfully present immigrants to receive subsidies on the health exchange if you meet the proper income ratios.

In order to obtain the insurance, you can apply through the healthcare marketplace at https://healthcare.gov